# How can I filter the friends returned from a facebook graph API request?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to retrieve all facebook friends which match some sort of filter or pattern. I am currently calling this:

me/friends?fields=name,id

This returns all friends which have also downloaded my app. However, is there a way to filter the returned friends by name? I want to avoid retrieving all friends and then filtering the results on the client side to minimise the size of the result since there could be a lot of results. I know that FQL supported this, but it has been deprecated in favour of the graph API, however despite looking around everywhere I am surprised to not have found an answer to what I thought would be a pretty common requirement.

To give a bit of context, I'm simply providing the user with a text field with which they can filter their friends, and so want to make requests on the graph API like this:

me/friends?fields=name,id&name=%Pat%

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to get a specific friends or do you want to get the friends that don't have the app? Please clarify please what friends you are trying to get

Comment: I'm aware that I only have access to friends who have downloaded the app, that's fine. I want to further filter the friends who have the app by some name pattern matching. Does this clarify?

Comment: The API does not provide such functionality. // I don’t think you should worry about the size of the response to much here. Even for a user with a couple of hundred of friends who are also using the same app, the resulting JSON should still be a few KB only.

Comment: ok great, I guess I can download it once and reuse through out the app, which I presume is what everyone is doing. Thanks a lot, at least I now know to proceed now! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK gives you the option to retrieve either the friends that use the application or the one who haven't downloaded it yet (for invitation purposes etc.)
However, if you would like to filter them you will have to do it in the FE. Facebook SDK doesn't support such functionality yet.

Cheers